# How to eager load associations with the current_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, devise, eager-loading

I'm using Devise for authentication in my Rails app. I'd like to eager load some of a users associated models in some of my controllers. Something like this:

```
class TeamsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @team = Team.includes(:members).find params[:id]
    current_user.includes(:saved_listings)

    # normal controller stuff
  end
end
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Overwrite the current_user method

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and although everyone keeps saying there's no need to do this, I found that there is, just like you. So this works for me:

```
# in application_controller.rb:
def current_user
  @current_user ||= super && User.includes(:saved_listings).find(@current_user.id)
end
```

Note that this will load the associations in *all* controllers. For my use case, that's exactly what I need. If you really want it only in *some* controllers, you'll have to tweak this some more.

This will also call `User.find` twice, but with query caching that shouldn't be a problem, and since it prevents a number of additional DB hits, it still is a performance gain.

Comment: I haven't tested it but it looks good to me. Would be easy to make this accept an argument representing an array of table names to include also.

Comment: Note that since Rails 4, this answer using `#find` _does_ trigger two separate database queries on `users`. The implementation of `#first` (used by [`OrmAdapter::ActiveRecord#get`](https://github.com/ianwhite/orm_adapter/blob/v0.5.0/lib/orm_adapter/adapters/active_record.rb#L15-L18), which Devise calls to serialize its `current_user` object) in Rails 4+ adds an `ORDER BY users.id ASC` clause while `#find` does not, so the two queries no longer match in the query cache. `User.includes(:saved_listings).where(id: @current_user.id).first` will match across Rails versions.

Comment: +1 for the DB queries above. This can potentially be an expensive solution. Look for a better alternative me and my teammate found in a separate answer using `ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader`

Comment: I agree this is a good solution. But for more advanced cases this link might be helpful - https://blog.widefix.com/parameterized-rails-associations/

Answer (score 17):

Override [`serialize_from_session`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v4.1.1/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L207) in your `User` model.

```
class User
  devise :database_authenticatable

  def self.serialize_from_session key, salt
    record = where(id: key).eager_load(:saved_listings, roles: :accounts).first
    record if record && record.authenticatable_salt == salt
  end
end
```

This will however, eager load on *all* requests.

Comment: The currently selected answer by Thilo above results in a lot more queries. If the intent is to eager load associated models in current_user to reduce the number of queries, overriding the class method, demonstrated in this answer, is the way to go.

Comment: A slightly more improved version of this is to use `ActiveRecord::Relation#scoping` then call super in the scoping block. Like `eager_load(:saved_listings, roles: :accounts).scoping { super(key, salt) }`.

Answer (score 16):

I wanted to add what I think is a better solution. As noted in comments, existing solutions may hit your DB twice with the `find` request. Instead, we can use `ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader` to leverage Rails' work around loading associations:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= super.tap do |user|
    ::ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new.preload(user, :saved_listings)
  end
end
```

This will re-use the existing model in memory instead of joining and querying the entire table again.

Comment: This is by far the best answer, thanks. You could also make a convenience method to make it explicit for the callee.

def current_user_with(includes)
            @current_user_with ||= current_user.tap do |user|
              ::ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new.preload(user, includes)
            end
          end

Answer (score -3):

Why not do it with default_scope on the model?

like so:

```rb
Class User  < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  default_scope includes(:saved_listings)
  ...
end
```

Comment: Then every query on `User` will eager load the saved listings (tests included). This is overkill if you only want to eager load in one or two actions and will have a negative effect on the response time of the application and the speed of the test suite.

Comment: Just a thought... If your `current_user` belongs to a company as well as all other users in the table and if you constantly refer to the company attributes of the returned users or current_user, wouldn't it make sense to have this? Also, Rails 4.2.1 (don't know about previous versions) does not allow `default_scope` without a block, so you would have to call `default_scope { includes(:company) }`